# get all groups from the Users - sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

In sfDoctrineGuardPlugin is:

```
sfGuardUser:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    first_name: string(255)
    last_name: string(255)
    //
  indexes:
    is_active_idx:
      fields: [is_active]
  relations:
    Groups:
      class: sfGuardGroup
      local: user_id
      foreign: group_id
      refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
      foreignAlias: Users



sfGuardGroup:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    name:
      type: string(255)
      unique: true
    description: string(1000)
  relations:
    Users:
      class: sfGuardUser
      refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
      local: group_id
      foreign: user_id
      foreignAlias: Groups

sfGuardUserGroup:
  options:
    symfony:
      form:   false
      filter: false
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    group_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: user_id
      onDelete: CASCADE
    Group:
      class: sfGuardGroup
      local: group_id
      onDelete: CASCADE
```

This is relation many to many and how can i get all groups of User?

> - @method Doctrine_Collection
>     getGroups()                Returns the
>     current record's "Groups" collection

i make:

```
$this->groups = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getGroups();
```

this return:

```
 Doctrine_Collection data : Array( )
```

how can i check whether the user is on group TEST?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the sfGuardSecurityUser class: https://github.com/Garfield-fr/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/blob/master/lib/user/sfGuardSecurityUser.class.php

```
if ($this->getUser()->hasGroup('TEST')) {
    //if user is on group TEST
}//end if

// get all groups

$userGroups = $this->getUser()->getGroups();
```

Comment: thanks, but i use $userGroups then i have: "<pre> Doctrine_Collection data : Array( 0 : Object(sfGuardGroup) ) </pre>" how can i show it? :) foreach and .. ?

Comment: @Tony Oriondo: If you not not set groups to your user, the getGroups method return an empty array. Are you sure you set group to your user?

Answer (score 1):

you may try using a query to find groups of your user:

```
$user_id = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId();
$groups = Doctrine_core::getTable('sfGuardGroup')->create_query('g')->innerJoin('g.users u with u.id= ?', $user_id);
```