# Create new users with the same group(s) as the user logged in

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I'm trying to add new users to sfDoctrineGuard table using my own register form. This is the configure function I made:

```
public function configure() {
    // Remove all widgets we don't want to show
    unset(
            $this['is_super_admin'], $this['updated_at'], $this['groups_list'], $this['permissions_list'], $this['last_login'], $this['created_at'], $this['salt'], $this['algorithm']
    );

    $id_empresa = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getSfGuardUserProfile()->getIdempresa();
    $this->setDefault('idempresa', $id_empresa);

    $this->validatorSchema['idempresa'] = new sfValidatorPass();

    $this->widgetSchema['first_name'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
    $this->widgetSchema['last_name'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
    $this->widgetSchema['username'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
    $this->widgetSchema['email_address'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
    $this->widgetSchema['password'] = new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
    $this->widgetSchema['password_confirmation'] = new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));

    // Setup proper password validation with confirmation
    $this->validatorSchema['password']->setOption('required', true);
    $this->validatorSchema['password_confirmation'] = clone $this->validatorSchema['password'];

    $this->widgetSchema->moveField('password_confirmation', 'after', 'password');

    $this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('password', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::EQUAL, 'password_confirmation', array(), array('invalid' => 'The two passwords must be the same.')));
}
```

Now I need to create those new users with the same group(s) that the user logged in but I don't know how. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526202/get-all-groups-from-the-users-sfdoctrineguardplugin) but don't know if using `getGroups()` will do the job I mean setting `groups_list` default, any advice? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several way you could do this... I'd recommend adding the groups once validation for the other fields has taken place, and the user object has been saved; so you can override the `save()` function of the form and add them there:

```
<?php

class YourUserForm extends PluginsfGuardUserForm
{
  /**
   * A class variable to store the current user
   * @var sfGuardUser
   */
  protected $current_user;

  public function configure()
  {
    // Remove all widgets we don't want to show
    unset(
      $this['is_super_admin'],
      $this['updated_at'],
      $this['groups_list'],
      $this['permissions_list'],
      $this['last_login'],
      $this['created_at'],
      $this['salt'],
      $this['algorithm']
    );

    // save the currrent user for use later in the save function
    $this->current_user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser();

    $id_empresa = $this->current_user->getSfGuardUserProfile()->getIdempresa();;
    $this->setDefault('idempresa', $id_empresa);

    $this->validatorSchema['idempresa'] = new sfValidatorPass();

    $this->widgetSchema['first_name'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
    $this->widgetSchema['last_name'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
    $this->widgetSchema['username'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
    $this->widgetSchema['email_address'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
    $this->widgetSchema['password'] = new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
    $this->widgetSchema['password_confirmation'] = new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));

    // Setup proper password validation with confirmation
    $this->validatorSchema['password']->setOption('required', true);
    $this->validatorSchema['password_confirmation'] = clone $this->validatorSchema['password'];

    $this->widgetSchema->moveField('password_confirmation', 'after', 'password');

    $this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('password', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::EQUAL, 'password_confirmation', array(), array('invalid' => 'The two passwords must be the same.')));
  }

  public function save($con = null)
  {
    // call the parent function to perform the save and get the new user object
    $new_user = parent::save($con); /* @var $user sfGuardUser */

    // add our groups here by looping the current user's group collection
    foreach($this->current_user->getGroups() as $group) /* @var $group sfGuardGroup */
    {
      // we could use $user->addGroupByName($group->name); here, but it would mean
      // an extra db lookup for each group as it validates the name. we know the
      // group must exist, so can just add directly

      // create and save new user group
      $ug = new sfGuardUserGroup();
      $ug->setsfGuardUser($new_user);
      $ug->setsfGuardGroup($group);

      $ug->save($con);
    }

    // make sure we return the user object
    return $new_user;
  }
}
```

You can see I set up a class variable to store the current user, this isn't necessary, but it save having to keep calling `sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser()`, and is good practice as your forms get more complex.

Hopefully this helps! :)

Comment: good answer +1, now I wish to know instead of save all the groups as the main post said, just to save lets said the group called "Group 1", it's possible too? how?

Comment: Thanks @Reynier! If you know the group name, just replace the `foreach` loop with:`$new_user->addGroupByName('Your group name');`

Comment: excellent, it works. One last question: I've a relation with `sfGuardUserProfile` table and I like also to set the `$id_empresa` for the new created user, how? can I access from method `save()` to `setSfGuardUserProfile()` method which is in `BasesfGuardUser` class?